# SVG: how to color the whole image

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Here is the SVG image I have: https://jsfiddle.net/hey0qvgk/3/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" width="90" height="90" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 613.2 416" style="enable-background:new 0 0 613.2 416;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .video-svg{fill:#00648F;}
</style>
<g>
    <path id="video-svg" class="video-svg" d="M346.7,415.8H69c-38,0-69-30.9-69-69V69.1c0-38,30.9-68.9,69-68.9h277.8c38,0,69,30.9,69,68.9v277.7
        C415.7,384.9,384.8,415.8,346.7,415.8z M69,33.9c-19.4,0-35.2,15.8-35.2,35.2v277.7c0,19.4,15.8,35.2,35.2,35.2h277.8
        c19.4,0,35.2-15.8,35.2-35.2V69.1c0-19.4-15.8-35.2-35.2-35.2H69z"/>
    <path id="video-svg" class="video-svg" d="M596.3,354.1c-3.3,0-6.6-1-9.5-2.9l-115-78.1c-4.6-3.1-7.4-8.4-7.4-13.9V156.8c0-5.6,2.8-10.8,7.4-13.9
        l115-78.1c5.2-3.5,11.9-3.8,17.4-1c5.5,2.9,9,8.7,9,14.9v258.6c0,6.2-3.4,12-9,14.9C601.7,353.5,599,354.1,596.3,354.1z
         M498.2,250.2l81.3,55.2V110.5l-81.3,55.2V250.2z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

As you may see - only the path (the "borders" of the image) is colored. However, I need the whole image to be filled with specific color (it should be colored "inside" as well). I'm new to svg - could you please tell me what I have to do to color the whole image?

Comment: background and background-color doesn't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Your `svg` path have the strokes converted to shapes.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/elrumordelaluz/wL1fk9x5/1/) you could see:

- the first `svg`, same as yours edited in Illustrator to modify the paths.
- the second is an `svg` recreated using stroke and not converting it to shapes. It allows you to control both the `stroke` and the `fill` through `css` (in my example).

Comment: I see. So, my image needs to be edited in Adobe Illustrator anyway, the problem cannot be solved just by adding/changing some attributes manually. Ok, thanks for response. I'll probably ask the one who sent me images (this one is not the only) to send me new versions that can be colored inside.

Answer (score 0):

Your icon consist of two paths.  One is the body of the camera. The other forms the "lens".

Each of those two paths consists of two subpaths.  One forms the outside edge of the shape, and the other forms the inside (the hole that makes the inside transparent).

So for example the first path is the camera "body".  Here is its path definition:

```
# the "outside"
M346.7,415.8H69c-38,0-69-30.9-69-69V69.1c0-38,30.9-68.9,69-68.9h277.8
c38,0,69,30.9,69,68.9v277.7C415.7,384.9,384.8,415.8,346.7,415.8z

# the "hole"
M69,33.9c-19.4,0-35.2,15.8-35.2,35.2v277.7c0,19.4,15.8,35.2,35.2,35.2
h277.8c19.4,0,35.2-15.8,35.2-35.2V69.1c0-19.4-15.8-35.2-35.2-35.2H69z
```

Each subpath starts with an 'M' (move) and ends with a 'z' (close path).

In the case of this icon the subpath that forms the hole is the second subpath in each `<path>` element.  If you delete the two hole subpaths you get:

```html
<svg version="1.1" width="90" height="90" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 613.2 416" style="enable-background:new 0 0 613.2 416;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .video-svg{fill:#00648F;}
</style>
<g>
 <path id="video-svg" class="video-svg" d="M346.7,415.8H69c-38,0-69-30.9-69-69V69.1c0-38,30.9-68.9,69-68.9h277.8c38,0,69,30.9,69,68.9v277.7
  C415.7,384.9,384.8,415.8,346.7,415.8z"/>
 <path id="video-svg" class="video-svg" d="M596.3,354.1c-3.3,0-6.6-1-9.5-2.9l-115-78.1c-4.6-3.1-7.4-8.4-7.4-13.9V156.8c0-5.6,2.8-10.8,7.4-13.9
  l115-78.1c5.2-3.5,11.9-3.8,17.4-1c5.5,2.9,9,8.7,9,14.9v258.6c0,6.2-3.4,12-9,14.9C601.7,353.5,599,354.1,596.3,354.1z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

You can either choose to edit the file graphically with Illustrator, or you can edit it manually like I have.  Be aware though, that not all files will be as straightforward to manually modify as this one.